# Change Permission Dialog Color

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10

I am currently building a UWP app which overrides user's accent colors.

I changed it this way:

```
        <Color x:Key="SystemAccentColor">#fff001</Color>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush" Color="{StaticResource SystemAccentColor}" />
```

Now every control in the app uses this accent color, which is pretty great!

But then the Permission Dialog still has the user's accent color. For example, I use Blue as accent color and this permission dialog doesn't use the new accent color (#fff001) but instead uses the blue one!

[Permission Dialog example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2nqQ.png)

Is there any way to override the color of this permission dialog? I also already edited the Background Color in the Manifest file (Package.appxmanifest -> Visual Assets -> Background Color), still no luck.

Comment: In build 14393 (Anniversary), the SolidColorBrush resource to override is SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush .  Try to change this and let me know if its working or not

Comment: @GaurangDave    I used this one too now          <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush " Color="{StaticResource SystemAccentColor}" /> and it still does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Permission Dialog Color depend on the device system color, user can configure it in the Settings app=> Personalization=> Colors. If you want to change it, you can provide a link to the [personalization-colors settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app) to suggest the user to change it and you can not change it in your app directly.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to change the style of the permissions dialog, as this is a "system" dialog, which only provides means to grant your app a permission, but is not technically part of your application.